# A question from cosmological perturbation theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, perturbation-theory

We consider the following scalar perturbation on the FRW metric
$$ds^2=-(1+2\Phi)dt^2+2a(\partial_iB)dx^idt+a^2[(1-2\Psi)\delta_{ij}+2\partial_{ij}E]dx^idx^j,$$
where $\Phi$, $B$, $\Psi$ and $E$ are perturbations and $a$ is the scale factor.

Now consider a gauge (coordinate) transformation:
$$t\rightarrow t+\alpha,\\\
x^i\rightarrow x^i+\delta^{ij}\partial_j\beta.$$
It is stated that we have the scalar metric perturbation transform as 
$$\Phi\rightarrow \Phi-\dot{\alpha},\tag{1}$$
$$B\rightarrow B+a^{-1}\alpha-a\dot{\beta},\tag{2}$$
$$E\rightarrow E-\beta,\tag{3}$$
$$\Psi\rightarrow \Psi+H\alpha.\tag{4}$$
$H$ is the Hubble constant.

I have checked (1)~(3). But I can not derive Eq.(4). Eq.(4) even looks very strange if we take a quick check, setting $\alpha$ to be a small constant and $\beta=0$. Then we have 
$$dt\rightarrow dt$$
$$dx^i\rightarrow dx^i.$$

How can the above gauge transformation induce a change of $\Psi$? Thank you very much for your help.

***I now understand where $H\alpha$ is from. It is from $a^2(\tilde{t})=a^2(t)\left(1-H(t)\alpha(t)\right)$***

Comment: Is there a possibility that you could show how you derived equation (3) and (4) since I'm stuck with these. I'm trying to get to those equation by using the transformation law of the metric

Answer (score 0):

You should also take into account that after the coordinate transformation you take the value in the different point. The simplest example would be a scalar field,
\begin{equation}
\Phi(x^\mu)+\phi(x^\mu)\mapsto \Phi(x^\mu-\xi^\mu)+\phi(x^\mu-\xi^\mu)\simeq \Phi(x^\mu)+\Big(\phi(x)-\xi^\mu\partial_\mu\Phi\Big)
\end{equation}
Therefore its perturbation transforms as,
\begin{equation}
\phi(x)\mapsto \phi(x)-\xi^\mu\partial_\mu\Phi
\end{equation}
This adds similar term to all perturbations.